# Исправить программу по отражению матриц

Tags: c++, c, матрицы

Дана квадратная случайная матрица. Нужно зеркально отразить ее элементы
относительно побочной диагонали и вывести матрицы рядом друг с другом

Программа ломается после половины, не понимаю как исправить. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить. Заранее спасибо!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
int st,str,k=0,x;
printf("введите количество столбцов \n");
  scanf("%d",&st);
printf("введите количество строк \n");
  scanf("%d",&str);
int a[str][st];
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
{
  printf("\n");
  for (int j = 0; j<st; j++)
{
  a[i][j] =-99 + rand()%199;
  printf("%4d ",a[i][j]);
}
printf("  |  ");
  for (int j = 0; j<st; j++)
{  
  printf("%4d ",a[j][i]);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала инициализировать всю матрицу, а потом уже выводить её и её зеркальную версию.

Вот пример кода:

```
int st,str,k=0,x;
printf("введите количество столбцов \n");
scanf("%d",&st);
printf("введите количество строк \n");
scanf("%d",&str);
int a[str][st];
srand(time(NULL));

//Инициализация
for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < st; j++)
        a[i][j] = -99 + rand() % 199;

//Вывод
for (int i = 0; i < str; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < st; j++)
        printf("%4d ", a[i][j]);
    printf("  |  ");
    for (int j = 0; j < st; j++)
        printf("%4d ", a[j][i]);
}
```